# Function to convert milliseconds into epoch or long in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am able to convert upto seconds by using this query

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + 1362508200000(06/032013 00:00:00)/1000
       * INTERVAL '1 second'
```

But I want to convert into milliseconds, (06/032013 00:00:00.625362)

Answer (score 1):

```
postgres=# select extract(epoch from current_timestamp);
    date_part     
------------------
 1370602871.47581
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_timestamp(1370602871.47581);
         to_timestamp         
------------------------------
 2013-06-07 13:01:11.47581+02
(1 row)
```